# Will nanochaff of radius 5nm act as an electrical conductor for the purposes of jamming radar?

Tags: electrical-engineering, aluminum, radar, reflective-coatings

I was reading a great paper about nanochaff recently and I was wondering how small it could be made while still diffracting in the radio spectrum. Does anyone know if 5nm diameter chaff would still be useful for diffraction in the radio spectrum?

Article: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1176/6/062002/pdf